# CFType for NSArray and NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, cftypes

We are working in a way to make a fixed array (and all its fixed components, in several levels) mutable, and it seems that the only way to do it is iterate through all the levels in the nested fixed arrays and create mutable objects either using `arrayWithArray` or `mutableCopy`.

Doing some research I found that both `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray` return the same value (int 19) when the `CFgetCFType()` function is used.

Attached is the sample code

```
NSArray *array = @[@"one", @"two"];
NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array];
int id1 = CFGetTypeID((__bridge CFTypeRef)(array));
int id2 = CFGetTypeID((__bridge CFTypeRef)(mutableArray));
NSLog(@"Type: %i Type: %i", id1, id2);
```

Why is it, that both struct types return the same `CFTypeID`?. Does it mean that the mutability of `NSMutableArray` is hidden within the opaque definition of `CFMutableArrayRef`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSArray has a lot of extremely complicated and undocumented behaviour. It does some crazy stuff to improve real world performance.

The high level behaviour of `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray` is well documented but those two classes do not actually exist, instead you get instances of other classes, which class you actually get will depend on heuristic decisions the framework will make based on the actual data in the array and how you access it.

Creating copies of an array might not actually make a copy until you start modifying it. And even then, it may never make copies, it might keep the original array around and maintain a delta of changes that have been made.

If you need to know what is going on, then you should not be using `NSArray` at all. Instead you should drop to C arrays or perhaps even `NSMutableData` (tip: `NSMutableData` is awesome when the contents are potentially too big to fit in RAM).

The specific behaviour you are seeing could change at any time depending on the operating system version and perhaps even the hardware your app is executing on. Do not rely on how `NSArray` works in practice, because that is unpredictable. Instead rely on the documentation. Anything undocumented cannot be trusted, especially with `NSArray` which is a special case class.

Also, never ever subclass `NSArray`. Instead create a wrapper class that uses `NSArray` internally.

Answer (score 1):

I did some rough testing. It looks like the `CFTypeID` is the same for any array: big/small, static/runtime generated, and mutable/immutable. If I had to make a guess, I would guess that all classes in the `NSArray`/`CFArrayRef` cluster class group used the same CFTypeID.

It doesn't matter. That is an implementation detail on which you can't rely.